# What Does This Rails4 error mean? fatal: exception reentered ... `rescue in rollback_active_record_state!'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm getting a couple of errors in my Rails 4 appointment scheduling application that I can't seem to correct or figure out the root cause.

My seeds file keeps breaking with well known "error, stack level too deep". But when I run the method I believe it is breaking on, I get this different error:

```
Seeding time slots for workday no. 1
   (0.5ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
fatal: exception reentered
from /Users/rskelley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `rescue in rollback_active_record_state!'
```

The involved files are as follows.

**Seeds.rb**

```
puts "Seeding Workdays."

day_numbers = (1..5).to_a
5.times do
  start_time = WorkDay.time_slot_format(9)
  end_time = WorkDay.time_slot_format([5,6][rand(2)])
  rand_date = Date.today + day_numbers.slice!(0)
  WorkDay.create(start_time: start_time, end_time: end_time, date: rand_date )
end

puts "Generating Time Slots for each WorkDay"

workdays = WorkDay.all
workday_number = 1

workdays.each do |workday|
  calendar_manager = CalendarManager.new(workday: workday, date: workday.date)
  puts "Seeding time slots for workday no. #{workday_number}"
  workday_number += 1
  calendar_manager.generate_time_slots!
end
```

**calendar_manager.rb**

```
include ActiveModel::Validations
include ActiveModel::Conversion
extend ActiveModel::Naming
extend AppointmentTools

attr_accessor :workday, :date, :slot_length

 def generate_time_slots!(increment=15)
    # Space between start and end
    @slot_length ||= increment

    day = self.workday.date
    hour = 9
    minute = 0
    @time_slots = Array.new

    33.times do
      beginning = TimeOfDay.parse(hour) + minute.minutes
      ending = beginning + @slot_length.minutes
      time_slot = TimeSlot.create work_day_id: self.workday.id, start_time: beginning.strftime("%I:%M %p"), end_time: ending.strftime("%I:%M %p"), date: day
      @time_slots << time_slot
      minute += @slot_length
    end
  end
```

Going through my commit history, I am not aware of any changes made to the generate_time_slots! method, and it worked previously. I'm using Rails 4, Ruby 2.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm getting a similar error.   Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this was your error specifically, but I ran into this when I had two models that related to each other, both with `dependent: :destroy` on the relationship

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem ended up being a recursive method call in my TimeSlot model. I was using a :before_save Active Record callback to check and set the status attribute of a TimeSlot instance. The update would recursively catch the :before_save callback. At the time, I didn't put together what the method was indicating,. It helps to point out that it was specifically a fatal error, that it was breaking on save, and that there was a stack level too deep error when called externally.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So I just had a similar issue with a similar error message.

It is just that **ActiveRecord** is being "helpful" and telling you that you called the same method recursively.  Basically rather than saying you ran out of stack it is looking at the trace it originally got and determining it is in fact a reentered recursive call.

At least, that solved my issue.

Comment: This is correct, I accepted your answer. The recursion was in my TimeSlot model. I was using a :before_save callback to recursively check and set the status attribute of a TimeSlot instance.

Comment: ..The update would recursively catch the before_save condition, and re-enter the loop.

Comment: How can I find out which method is called recursively? This happens for me when there is nothing save in a GET request.